# Trouble with a partial integration problem

Tags: integration

The integral in question $$\int x^2(x+1)^{10} dx$$

So before we apply the formula, we have to choose $f'(x)$ and $g(x)$. Now to me there's only two options here, either $f'(x)=x^2$ or $f'(x)=(x+1)^{10}$. Now if we choose the first option, the solution might be correct, but it would be extremely labor intensive ( we would need to apply integration by parts around 10 times, carry around a dozen terms etc...). The latter option doesn't seem any better and I've tried it multiple times - result is wrong. Our formula in question $$\int f'(x)g(x) dx = f(x)g(x)-\int f(x)g'(x) dx$$

There's of course a third option. Applying the binomial theorem to get an expression with multiple terms, then integrating each member of that sum - but that would basically defeat the purpose of the problem.

My question is, what other ways are there to process this expression, such that we apply the technique of partial integration - while at the same time being efficient about it?

Comment: Choosing $g(x)=x^2$ and applying int. by parts twice should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x+1=t$, then the integral is
$$\int (t-1)^2t^{10} \, dt=\int t^{12}-2t^{11}+t^{10} \, dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Why not to let $x=t-1$ first ?
$$\int x^2(x+1)^{10} \,dx=\int(t-1)^2 t^{10} \,dt=\int(t^{12}-2t^{11}+t^{10})\,dt$$